# Android studio adjust EditText on top of ListView

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

I am trying to put EditText on top of ListView. Using Relative Layout, both EditText and ListView placed on the screen but text field is mixed with list view on top of page. I added some empty space but did not work.
How can I separate edittext and listview. Here is my present code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".InvoiceSearchList">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/invoiceSearchFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:hint="Search invoice"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewInvoiceSearchList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Result screenshot
[EditText mixed with ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9bm9.png)

Comment: At least from the image, it seems like the `ListView` is on top of the `EditText`. You can try changing the order of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/et1"></EditText>

  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et1"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just add ID on the Edit text and set `layout_below` property to Listview and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add marginTop for list view.

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/id"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
```

Comment: This is not the right approach. As you can not know what will be the exact height of the edit text box or any other element. You can check my answer below, that will work on any element. If it is helpful then please accept it so others can be benefited.

Comment: OK I will check. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Welcome. Please mark it as answered so everyone can get help from it.Thanks.